# Pegar total cores de imagem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Queria saber como pegar o total de cores de uma certa imagem, analisei alguns códigos de uns sites, e alguns utilizam ajax (jQuery) para enviar a imagem para uma página em PHP, mas não sei o que contém nessa página PHP, será que alguém poderia me auxiliar? Exemplo:

http://prntscr.com/90lnmx

Comment: O que poderia ser feito em PHP é utilizar a biblioteca GD (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.image.php) e percorrer com um laço a imagem pixel a pixel capturando e armazenando em uma array.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo de histograma em 3D usando JS: http://h3stogram.herokuapp.com/ O fonte está [disponivel no GitHub](https://github.com/aluarosi/h3stogram.js)

Comment: [**Não** reinvente a roda](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/).

Comment: Verdade @renan, ctrl c + ctrl v + alguns ajustes é mais prático com certeza, é que na verdade a pergunta dele diz que a imagem vai para uma página **PHP** e que ele não sabe o que contém nessa página **PHP**, eu disse o que poderia ter =)